# Python - access class attributes in another Class, which is not its child

Tags: python, oop

I'm working on some homework, where we started OOP and I'm not really confident in it.

Let's say I have X instances of class Card, where Card is parent class for another subclasses like type of the cards etc, but overall I have all of them saved in variable "instances", so for example 20 instances. What I need is to get 10 of these instances into another Class named Deck, where I will create new list "deck" and have those 10 cards in it, where I will afterwords split them in a half to the 2 players.

My problem there is that I just don't know how to move these instances from class Card to the class Deck and also split them afterwords for these two players. Thanks for your help, I hope I made myself clear.

```
class Card:

    instances = []

    def __init__(self, name):
         self.__name = name
         self.__class__.instances.append(self)

class Deck:
    
    deck = []

    def __init__(self):
         self.__class__.deck.append(Card.instances)    


class Player(Deck):
     
     def __init__(self, name, deck):
         super().__init__(deck)
         self.__name = name


def main():

     card1 = Card('Card1')
     card2 = Card('Card2')
     card3 = Card('Card3')

     p1 = Player('Tim')
     p2 = Player('Jill')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: The way Deck is implemented here, it is a list of _all_ cards, so you would never be able to have two different decks.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So how to possibly do that?

Comment: I'm not sure you even need a `Deck` class.  Just a plain list of cards seems like it would work fine.

Comment: Also, why are you inheriting the Player class from the Deck class?  This means that a player _is_ a deck, which seems odd.  I think it makes more sense to say that a player _has_ a deck (i.e. composition), not that a player _is_ a deck (i.e. inheritance).

Comment: Okay, but anyway. If I will have this list, how am I going to split it for these two players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, you implemented `Deck` so that it contains a list of all `Cards`. You will want to `init` a deck just with its name (and maybe a few starting cards) and then have methods in this class to add and withdraw any other cards. You can use the code below for this:

```
class Deck:

    def __init__(self, init_cards=None):
        self.deck = []
        if init_cards:
            self.deck.extend(init_cards)    
    
    def add_card(self, card):
        self.deck.append(card)
    
    def withdraw_card(self, card_name):
        return_card = None
        for card in self.deck:
            if card.name == card_name:
                return_card = self.deck.remove(card)
        return return_card
```

Next you can create the Decks with their cards and pass the cards between decks using the functions in the `Deck` class. Give each player a deck as a variable and then reference to it.

Comment: `__init__` probably wants to call `.extend(init_cards)`, not `.append(init_cards)`.